# Migrating Built-in Django Models When Upgrading

Tags: django, django-models, upgrade, data-migration, django-south

We're using an older version of Django (1.1.1) and are preparing to upgrade to the latest version (currently 1.2) soon.

None of my searches have brought up the topic of migrating database tables (auth_user, etc.) across Django versions. Using syncdb only works for creating new tables but has no effect on existing tables.

I'm under the impression that the upgrade is not simply linking to a new version of the Django files but that we also need to manage the migration of our database since we rely on some built-in Django apps (django.contrib.auth, django.contrib.sites, etc.). We're planning to use South to manage the database migration.

Is this something handled internally by Django? Am I trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no changes to the django.contrib.auth or django.contrib.sites models between 1.1.1 and 1.2.5 so you won't need to do any database migration.

Comment: Thanks. Where did you find this information? Is there somewhere I can look to verify if versions after 1.2.5 had any changes? The Django 1.2 release notes include changes to the django.contrib app internals but don't explicitly make mention of model changes.

Is it safe to assume that the django.contrib models aren't expected unless there's a major version change?

Comment: I downloaded both versions and compared the models.py files using vimdiff (plain diff would have worked too but I like the hilighting).

Comment: Another thing I could have done was comparing the output of `./manage.py sql auth sites` run against each version in a virtualenv. It's probably worth reading through http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/releases/1.2-alpha-1/ to understand the larger changes from 1.1 to 1.2.